# Tkinter bind inconsistency

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This problem appears to be hard to duplicate -- as I am able to correctly do it in a shorter program. What I'm hoping for is maybe some guidance on what could be going wrong. I have posted the version where it works correctly:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class DIS(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "program")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.usernameVar = StringVar()
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, contactQues, nowTry, next):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
            self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Here's a Button", command= lambda: controller.show_frame(nowTry))
        button2.pack()


class nowTry(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.entry1 = Entry(self)
        self.entry1.pack()

        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Yes", command = self.go)
        self.button1.pack()

        self.entry1.bind("<Return>", self.go)

    def go(self, event=None):
        print (self.entry1.get())
        self.controller.show_frame(contactQues)


class contactQues(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.entry1 = Entry(self)
        self.entry1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Submit", command= self.UsernameSubmit)
        self.button1.pack()

        self.entry1.bind("<Return>", self.UsernameSubmit)

    def UsernameSubmit(self, event=None):
        UsernameEntryGet = self.entry1.get()
        self.controller.usernameVar.set(UsernameEntryGet)
        self.controller.show_frame(next)


class next(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.controller.usernameVar)
        label.pack() ###Label is posted with input correctly
```

The issue I'm having with my main program is that the `self.controller.usernameVar` label does not post like it does in this example (nothing shows up at all) when the `Return` key is pressed to submit the input. However, when the `submit` button is clicked with the mouse, the label appears properly.

So, given this information, I feel as if my `bind("<Enter>"...` command is being managed wrong. I've tried `self.bind...`, `self.controller.bind...`, `self.entryX.bind...` without success.

Any ideas with this framework what could be wrong?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to make a shorter program illustrating the problem.

Comment: You really should remove all the excesive stuff from the code you post, and make sure that the code is actually runnable. Anyway. After adding the needed code for getting the window to show i got it running, and it seems to me like it is running and showing the entry in the label as it should.

Comment: I was trying to show the main framework in case somebody ran into this issue before. I'll consider revising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. The issue was that in my full program, I had multiple `bind` commands. While I was trying to solve this issue, I had some `entry` prompts bound to the `controller` and others to the `entry` itself (e.g,. `self.controller.bind` in a few classes and `self.entry.bind` in others).

I changed them all to `self.entry.bind` and it apparently fixed it -- which is why this code snippet worked as expected.